# File Mapping. Можно ли использовать WriteFile и ReadFile

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Есть код

```
void LetMeMapFlie(){
    // Создаем файлы
    FMP.writefile = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 255, MFName_w);
    FMP.readfile  = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READONLY,  0, 255, MFName_r);

    // Открываем файлы
    FMP.write = MapViewOfFile(FMP.writefile, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0,0,0);
    FMP.read  = MapViewOfFile(FMP.readfile,  FILE_MAP_READ, 0,0,0);

}
```

Далее есть функции, оставшиеся у меня от работы с  трубами

```
void WriteChar_SlimRG(unsigned char key){
    WriteFile(pipe1Write, &key, sizeof(unsigned char), &out_pipe_b, NULL)
}
```

Могу ли я тупо заменить *pipe1Write* на хэндл файла

Или есть какой-то особый подход записи байтов или INTов в Map File?

P.S. В англ. яз. не оч. шарю (Google Translate) - поэтому не следует думать, что я не посещал офф. сайт майкрософта. Но понять этот момент - не понял.

Comment: `MapViewOfFile` возвращает адрес участка памяти, на который отображен файл или его часть. Для того, чтобы работать с адресами, а не использовать файловые операции.

Comment: @MBo т.е. не прокатит через ReadFile и WriteFile?
А можете пример, как записать байт через MapViewOfFile.
Не очень представляю как это сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MapViewOfFile` возвращает адрес участка памяти, на который отображен файл или его часть. Для того, чтобы работать с адресами, а не использовать файловые операции.

Полученный указатель можно привести к нужному типу - например, `char*` и обращаться, как к массиву.

```
char* data = (char*)MapViewOfFile(...
data[3] = 42;
```

ReadFile и WriteFile тут совсем ни при чём

Comment: А изменения, если, например, у меня клиент читает, а сервер пишет - сразу обрабатываются?

Comment: Или после UnMap

Comment: Если обе программы обращаются к одному объекту - изменения будут сразу, это один из базовых способов IPC (межпрограммного взаимодействия). Надо только обеспечить синхронизацию, чтобы не прочитать недописанное.